# Программа-переводчик единиц измерений

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день
Попросили написать программу-переводчик единиц измерений. Программа должна генерировать случайное число и единицу измерения, потом случайным образом выбирать какой ответ я должен вставить(единицу или число), потом найти ответ и проверить. Что неправильно?
класс для исчислений и хранилище

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import java.util.Random;

/**
* Created by Admin on 24.01.2018.
*/

public class Logika {
int cisloPriklad;
String [] poleJednotek = {"","mm","cm","dm","m","km","l"};
String jednotkaPriklad;

int stupenPriklad;
int stupenReseni;
int randomCisloJednotkaPriklad;
int cisloJednotkaReseni;
int randomVyber;
float vysledekCislo;
Random random = new Random();

public void logikaVysledekCislo(int cisloPriklad, int randomCisloJednotkaPriklad, int stupenPriklad, int cisloJednotkaReseni, int stupenReseni){

    float pups = cisloPriklad;
    float irr;
    float ir;

    if (cisloJednotkaReseni == 7){
            cisloJednotkaReseni = 3;
            stupenReseni = 3;
        }
    if (stupenPriklad>1){
        for(int i = 2;i<=stupenPriklad;i++){
            pups = pups/cisloPriklad;
        }
    }
    int promenna = randomCisloJednotkaPriklad-cisloJednotkaReseni;
    int jednotkaPlogika = randomCisloJednotkaPriklad;
    int jednotkaRlogika = cisloJednotkaReseni;
    if (promenna<0){
        irr = pups/Math.abs(10*promenna);
        if (randomCisloJednotkaPriklad == 5){
            irr = irr / 100;
        }
        ir = irr;
        if (stupenReseni>1){
            for(int i = 2;i==stupenReseni;i++){
                ir = ir*irr;
            }
            this.vysledekCislo=ir;
        }
    }
    else {

        irr = cisloPriklad*Math.abs(10*promenna);
        if (cisloJednotkaReseni == 5){
            irr = irr * 100;
        }
        ir = irr;
        if (stupenReseni>1){
            for(int i = 2;i==stupenReseni;i++){
                ir = ir*irr;
            }
            this.vysledekCislo=ir;
        }
    }
}

public void logikaRandomVyber(){this.randomVyber = random.nextInt(1);}
public int getRandomVyber() {return randomVyber;}


public void logikaCisloPriklad(){this.cisloPriklad = random.nextInt(99)+1;}
public int getCisloPriklad() {return cisloPriklad;}


public String[] getPoleJednotek() {return poleJednotek;}

public void setJednotkaPriklad(String jednotkaPriklad) {this.jednotkaPriklad = jednotkaPriklad;}

public void logikaEnableStupenPriklad(int randomCisloJednotka){
    switch (randomCisloJednotka){
        case 6:
                this.stupenPriklad = 1;
                break;}}
public void logikaStupenPriklad(int randomCisloJednotkaPriklad){switch (randomCisloJednotkaPriklad){
    case 7: this.stupenReseni = 1;
        break;
    default: this.stupenReseni = random.nextInt(2)+1;
        break;
}}
public int getStupenPriklad() {return stupenPriklad;}

public void logikaStupenReseni(int cisloJednotkaReseni){
    switch (cisloJednotkaReseni){
        case 7: this.stupenReseni = 1;
        break;
        default: this.stupenReseni = random.nextInt(2)+1;
        break;
    }
}
public int getStupenReseni() {return stupenReseni;}


public int getRandomCisloJednotkaPriklad() {return randomCisloJednotkaPriklad;}

public void logikaRandomCisloJednotkaPriklad(){this.randomCisloJednotkaPriklad = random.nextInt(6)+1;}


public int getCisloJednotkaReseni() {return cisloJednotkaReseni;}
public void logikaCisloJednotkaReseni (int randomCisloJednotkaPriklad){
    if (randomCisloJednotkaPriklad == 7){
        randomCisloJednotkaPriklad = 3;
        this.stupenReseni = 3;
    }
    switch (randomCisloJednotkaPriklad){
        case 1: this.cisloJednotkaReseni = random.nextInt(5)+2;break;
        case 2: int pup2 = random.nextInt(4)+3;
        int pop2 = 1;
        int pip2[] = {pop2,pup2};
        this.cisloJednotkaReseni = pip2[random.nextInt(1)];
        break;
        case 3:int pup3 = random.nextInt(3)+4;
            int pop3 = random.nextInt(1)+1;
            int pip3[] = {pop3,pup3};
            this.cisloJednotkaReseni = pip3[random.nextInt(1)];
            break;
        case 4:int pup4 = random.nextInt(2)+5;
            int pop4 = random.nextInt(2)+1;
            int pip4[] = {pop4,pup4};
            this.cisloJednotkaReseni = pip4[random.nextInt(1)];
            break;
        case 5: int pup5 = random.nextInt(1)+6;
            int pop5 = random.nextInt(3)+1;
            int pip5[] = {pop5,pup5};
            this.cisloJednotkaReseni = pip5[random.nextInt(1)];
            break;
        case 6: int pup6 = 7;
            int pop6 = random.nextInt(4)+1;
            int pip6[] = {pop6,pup6};
            this.cisloJednotkaReseni = pip6[random.nextInt(1)];
            break;}}


public float getVysledekCislo() {
    return vysledekCislo;
}}
```

основной класс

```
package com.example.admin.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView textView;
        EditText editTextCislo;
    EditText editTextJednotka;
    EditText editTextStupen;
    TextView textViewPriklad;
    TextView textViewStupen;
    Button buttonProverka;
    Logika logika = new Logika();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        editTextCislo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCislo);
        editTextJednotka = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextJednotka);
        editTextStupen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStupen);
        textViewPriklad = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPriklad);
        textViewStupen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPriklad);
        buttonProverka = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProverka);


        logika.logikaRandomVyber();
        int randomVyber = logika.getRandomVyber();
        logika.logikaCisloPriklad();
        int cisloPriklad = logika.getCisloPriklad();
        logika.logikaRandomCisloJednotkaPriklad();
        int randomCisloJednotkaPriklad = logika.getRandomCisloJednotkaPriklad();
        String poleJednotek[] = logika.getPoleJednotek();
        String jednotkaPriklad = poleJednotek[randomCisloJednotkaPriklad];
        logika.setJednotkaPriklad(jednotkaPriklad);
        logika.logikaStupenPriklad(randomCisloJednotkaPriklad);
        textViewPriklad.setText(cisloPriklad + " " + jednotkaPriklad);
        logika.logikaEnableStupenPriklad(randomCisloJednotkaPriklad);
        int stupenPriklad = logika.getStupenPriklad();
        logika.logikaCisloJednotkaReseni(randomCisloJednotkaPriklad);
        int cisloJednotkaReseni = logika.getCisloJednotkaReseni();
        String textJednotkaReseni = poleJednotek[cisloJednotkaReseni];
        logika.logikaStupenReseni(cisloJednotkaReseni);
        int stupenReseni = logika.getStupenReseni();
        logika.logikaVysledekCislo(cisloPriklad,randomCisloJednotkaPriklad,stupenPriklad,cisloJednotkaReseni,stupenReseni);
        String vysledekCislo1 = Float.toString(logika.getVysledekCislo());
        switch (stupenPriklad){
            case 1:textViewStupen.setText(" ");
                break;
            default:
                textViewStupen.setText(stupenPriklad);
                break;
        }


        switch (randomVyber){
            case 0:

                switch (stupenReseni){
                    case 1:editTextStupen.setText(" ");
                        break;
                    default:
                        editTextStupen.setText(stupenReseni);
                        break;
                }

                editTextStupen.setText(stupenReseni);
                editTextCislo.setText(vysledekCislo1);
                editTextStupen.setEnabled(false);
                editTextStupen.setCursorVisible(false);
                editTextStupen.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                editTextStupen.setKeyListener(null);
                editTextCislo.setEnabled(false);
                editTextCislo.setCursorVisible(false);
                editTextCislo.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                editTextCislo.setKeyListener(null);
                break;

            case 1:
                switch (stupenReseni){
                    case 1:editTextStupen.setText(" ");
                        break;
                    default:
                        editTextStupen.setText(stupenReseni);
                        break;
                }
                editTextStupen.setText(stupenReseni);
                editTextJednotka.setText(textJednotkaReseni);
                editTextStupen.setEnabled(false);
                editTextStupen.setCursorVisible(false);
                editTextStupen.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                editTextStupen.setKeyListener(null);
                editTextJednotka.setEnabled(false);
                editTextJednotka.setCursorVisible(false);
                editTextJednotka.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                editTextJednotka.setKeyListener(null);
                break;
        }

        buttonProverka.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editTextCislo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCislo);
                editTextJednotka = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextJednotka);
                editTextStupen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStupen);
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

                String cisloEditTextCisloo = editTextCislo.getText().toString();
                float cisloEditTextCislo = Float.parseFloat(cisloEditTextCisloo);
                String textEditTextJednotka = editTextJednotka.getText().toString();
                int cisloJednotkaReseni = logika.getCisloJednotkaReseni();
                float vysledekCislo = logika.getVysledekCislo();
                String poleJednotek[] = logika.getPoleJednotek();
                String jednotkaReseni = poleJednotek[cisloJednotkaReseni];
                if (cisloEditTextCislo==vysledekCislo){
                    textView.setText("Spravne");
                }
                if (textEditTextJednotka==jednotkaReseni){
                    textView.setText("Spravne");
                }
                else {
                    textView.setText("Nespravne");
                }

    }
});}
}
```

Ошибка с которой вылетает (на строках editTextStupen.setText(stupenReseni);)

```
01-29 18:09:14.868 6385-6385/com.example.admin.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 6385
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.myapplication/com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                            Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
                                                                               at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4554)
                                                                               at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: не запускается из за editTextStupen.setText(stupenReseni), а также(когда они закоментированны) не видит правильный ответ logikaVysledekCislo или не видит правильный ответ String (logikaCisloJednotkaReseni). Программа должна, имея случайно сгенерированное число (cisloPriklad) и случайно сенерированную единицу измерения (randomCisloJednotkaPriklad) и степень(stupenReseni), найти правильный ответ(рамдомно выбираю между cisloJednotkaReseni и vysledekCislo)перевести из, например, сантиметров в дециметры, или имея число найти единицу измерения. Кстати поправил перевод из километров в другие единицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stupenReseni` имеет тип `int`, а метод `setText()` ожидает получить в качестве аргумента тип `String` или, если получает тип `int`, то считает его идентификатором ресурса типа `String`. Переданное вами в метод число не является идентификатором ресурса, о чем вы получаете ошибку (строка с указанным идентификатором не найдена).

Для того, чтобы вывести число методом `setText()` - это число нужно привести к типу `String`:

```
editTextStupen.setText(Integer.toString(stupenReseni));
```

или

```
editTextStupen.setText(String.valueOf(stupenReseni));
```

Данная операция не требуется, если при выводе используется конкатенация строк:

```
// здесь приведение к строковому типу будет выполнено автоматически
editTextStupen.setText("ответ: " + stupenReseni);
```

или через `String.format` (число после запятой будет подставлено на место *%d*

```
editTextStupen.setText(String.format("ответ: %d", stupenReseni));
```

то же касается и вывода других чисел в вашем коде.